# Do dwarf women have beards?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, books, dwarves

In light of Amazon's recent depiction of a [non-bearded dwarf woman](https://www.cbr.com/lord-of-the-rings-fan-demand-amazons-dwarf-queen-be-given-a-beard/), and some of the recent controversy around this, the question is what exactly did Tolkien say about bearded dwarf women?

Popular perception, no doubt heightened by the Peter Jackson films, have his lady dwarves as bearded, but did Tolkien actually ever say this?

Comment: It seems to me that the fact that Tolkien gave comparatively little thought to the dwarves should be obvious, because his entire body of work can be reasonably viewed as an excuse to spend more time developing an entire family of interrelated languages for Elves, while we only know approximately three words of Dwarvish.

Comment: @DougWarren Nevertheless, in the context of Tolkien, "comparatively little thought" is not that small.

Comment: @DougWarren He also gave comparatively little thought to female characters in general, so female dwarves were doubly snubbed.  An unfortunate lapse, but not uncommon in his day.

Comment: @DougWarren - Tolkien was a linguist, and _was_ developing a body of (elvin) languages, just for his own enjoyment. The history of that world was a side line, which he made up to explain details of his invented languages. Only later he was pushed to make it into a story and publish it… so your impression is right.

Comment: A bit off-topic but Pratchett's dwarves of both genders had beards. This is mostly explored with the dwarf Cheery and in the book The Truth.

Comment: A parody called Orconomics explains there are no female dwarves. A dwarve simply emerges from the forest occasionally with a child on his back. No dwarf has ever explained how, and they all steadfastly refuse to do so.

Answer (score 71):

### Quenta Silmarillion revisions (?1950–May 1951)

In c.1951, Tolkien wrote a revision to a chapter of *The Silmarillion* then titled "Of the Naugrim and the Edain", in which he explicitly stated that:

1. Dwarf women had beards
2. They had them from the beginning of their lives
3. Dwarves did not shave, and would probably die in shame if someone else shaved them (though this part is written with a male pronoun).
4. Dwarf woman and Dwarf men can not be told apart

> The Naugrim were ever, as they still remain, short and squat in stature; they were deep-breasted, strong in the arm, and stout in the leg, and their beards were long. Indeed this strangeness they have that no Man nor Elf has ever seen a beardless Dwarf- unless he were shaven in mockery, and would then be more like to die of shame than of many other hurts that to us would seem more deadly. **For the Naugrim have beards from the beginning of their lives, male and female alike; nor indeed can their womenkind be discerned by those of other race, be it in feature or in gait or in voice,** nor in any wise save this: that they go not to war, and seldom save at direst need issue from their deep bowers and halls. It is said, also, that their womenkind are few, and that save their kings and chieftains few Dwarves ever wed; wherefore their race multiplied slowly, and now is dwindling.
> <sub>"Of the Naugrim and the Edain" §5, first published in 1994 in *The War of the Jewels*</sub>

### The Lord of the Rings Appendices (?August 1954–?early 1955)

Shortly after this, when finishing up work for the appendices of *The Lord of the Rings*, Tolkien added a similar passage about Dwarf women.

As published in *The Lord of the Rings*, this one is a lot more vague, simply stating that dwarf woman look alike to dwarf men in voice, appearance, and garb, but without specifically mentioning beards.

> Dís was the daughter of Thráin II. She is the only dwarf-woman named in these histories. It was said by Gimli that there are few dwarf-women, probably no more than a third of the whole people. They seldom walk abroad except at great need. **They are in voice and appearance, and in garb if they must go on a journey, so like to the dwarf-men that the eyes and ears of other peoples cannot tell them apart.** This has given rise to the foolish opinion among Men that there are no dwarf-women, and that the Dwarves ‘grow out of stone’.
>
> It is because of the fewness of women among them that the kind of the Dwarves increases slowly, and is in peril when they have no secure dwellings. For Dwarves take only one wife or husband each in their lives, and are jealous, as in all matters of their rights. The number of dwarf-men that marry is actually less than one-third. For not all the women take husbands: some desire none; some desire one that they cannot get, and so will have no other. As for the men, very many also do not desire marriage, being engrossed in their crafts.
>
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Appendix A - 'III Durin's Folk</sub>

However, the passage used in the published text first appeared in a draft manuscript titled (titled "Notes on Chronology of Durin's Line"), and Christopher Tolkien notes that this earlier manuscript included a mention of beards.

> There is no difference in substance in [the preceding draft], except for the statements that they are never forced to wed against their will (which 'would of course be impossible'), **and that they have beards.**
> <sub>*The Peoples of Middle-earth* - Commentary on The Making of Appendix A - Durin's Folk</sub>

Christopher does not reproduce the earlier draft with the beards mention, and he does not speculate as to why his father edited it out. It could have been a deliberate decision to make it ambiguous, but it could have also been just a space constraint.

### Late note about beards (December 1972–September 1973)

Two decades later, Tolkien wrote a 2 1/2 page isolated note titled 'Beards' reflecting and expanding on a letter he had sent to a fan about beards. (The original letter is unpublished.)

In this note Tolkien said "All *male* Dwarves" had beards, underling the word male, leading to an implication that he may have been excluding females. However this was in reference to answering the question about which specific male characters had beards, and the note as a whole was mainly concerned with the affects of elvish ancestry on human beards, not with dwarves.

> A note was sent to Patricia Finney (Dec. 9/72), answering a question about *beards*, that mentioned some of the male characters which she and a friend did not imagine as having beards. *
>
> [Footnote on above:] * When I came to think of it, in my own imagination, beards were not found among Hobbits (as stated in text); nor among the Eldar (not stated). **All *male* Dwarves had them.** The wizards had them, though Radagast (not stated) had only short, curling, light brown hair on his chin. Men normally had them when full-grown, hence Eomer, Theoden and all others named. But not Denethor, Boromir, Faramir, Aragorn, Isildur, or other Númenórean chieftains.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - Beards</sub>

### Conclusion

- At the time that Tolkien was writing *The Lord of the Rings*, he envisioned female dwarves as being bearded.
- Tolkien may have intentionally decided to keep this ambiguous in the published book
- Tolkien may have changed his mind on this much later in life.

Comment: Tolkien? Inconsistent? Never!

Comment: @Valorum - I'd say that there's conclusive evidence that he at certain point he felt they had beards, and that there's some inconclusive evidence that he changed his mind later.

Comment: And there was me thinking the indistinguishability of male and female dwarves was a Pratchettism. Pratchett certainly took it to the logical social conclusion.

Comment: When I first read the Appendices, I thought Dwarf women wore male make-ups when they had to "go on a journey", like a lot of Chinese folk tales in which young women, who were required by tradition to stay home, put on male cloths and even fake beards, and snuck out to see the outside world (or to fight battles in the case of Mulan) - NoME isn't inconsistent with the Appendices this way.

Comment: Note that the composition dates used in this answer were taken from Hammond and Scull.

Comment: @ibid Maybe it's just me but Valorum's comment seems obviously ironic...

Comment: On the highlighted passage from the Appendix, if they are so alike that no other race can tell Dwarven women from Dwarven men, and *all* Dwarven men have beards, then by corollary that means that all Dwarven women also have beards. It'd be a dead giveaway otherwise. "Hey, I saw a dwarf the other day without a beard." "Oh, yeah, that's one of them *girl* dwarfs. Or maybe an oath-breaker, who knows."

Comment: Note that the female dwarf in question happens to be a *queen* - maybe it's just her royal prerogative to choose to shave so she stands out, while more typical dwarven women let their beards grow just like the men?

Comment: I think bearded female dwarves appeared in the background of the Hobbit films too.

Comment: @Cobalt - Not full bearded ones. More like some side burns.

Comment: Beard or no beard, there's no way you could say she is in "appearance, and in garb ... so like to [a] dwarf-[man] that the eyes and ears of other peoples cannot tell [her apart from other men]"

Comment: mild update: Patricia Finney no longer has a copy of the letter referred to here.

Comment: You could have also included the earlier version where Tolkien said there were no dwarf women, at which point the question was moot.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Do you have a specific passage in mind? Dwarf women already explicitly existed by the time *The Hobbit* was written ("*he was their mother's elder brother*"), and so I'd imagine anything earlier that stated otherwise would need to be so early as to be irrelevant to this question. I think this answer contains all known passages about Dwarf women that can be said to be contemporary or later to the writing of hobbit/lotr. I don't think BoLT dwarves can even be said to be the same race as LotR dwarves.

Comment: @ibid hmm. I don't have _The Lost Road and Other Writings_, so I can't check the Later Annals of Beleriand, where Dwarves are said to return to stone, and were 'made by Aulë', if it says anything specific. But I wouldn't be surprised if there was something even as late as that. I also don't have The History of The Hobbit, so I can't date/track that sentence talking about the mother of Fili and Kili.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Much of the material in *HoMe V* refers to dwarves in that way, that they were created by Aule out of stone, have no souls, and so return to stone when they die. (Though this is generally stated with some qualifier like "the Noldor believed".) But nothing is specifically said about dwarf women, or even about how dwarves reproduce. Rateliff says that the line from *The Hobbit* was added in the autumn 1936 typescript, 3.5 years after the rest of the book was finished. (In the original draft Fili and Kili survived.) I'd say both of these are roughly contemporary.

Comment: @ibid ok, thanks for confirming, and also for the dating of the sentence in question. I've asked someone who I think knows the answer. Maybe it's BoLT, as you suggest.

Comment: @ibid I never got an answer, but I note that in the _Tale of the Nauglafring_ is says "never child comes a among them [the Dwarves]". I haven't done an exhaustive search, though.