# How close is Amazon's 'The Rings of Power' to anything that existed in prior Tolkien works?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power, tolkiens-legendarium

I was interested in watching 'The Rings of Power' as I enjoy most of what has been produced on Tolkien's works (minus 'The Hobbit'). I am hearing some horrible reviews, however, that make me question if this is really related to anything Tolkien produced. I have not read the Silmarillion but I would hope some of the stories correlate to the new series. Is 'The Rings of Power' just fan fiction or is it based on any of Tolkien's writings?

edit:

Any update on this after the season finale? Did the season follow established stories?

Comment: They have beardless (or at least largely beardless) and clearly female dwarves .. for anyone who knows Tolkien's works that probably says it all .. if they're willing to be that cavalier with such a well known piece of the source materials established and original lore it doesn't bode well for anything else.

Comment: @Pelinore - Can't tell if you are joking or not. Dwarf beards is something Tolkien briefly touched upon [in like three unpublished notes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260738/do-dwarf-women-have-beards/260739#260739). Hardly something I'd describe as "well known" and "established".

Comment: Considering only two episodes out of the five-season TV show have been released so far, this question should be closed in line with our [Future Works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187/7957).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I will be answering this question by showing the correspondence between stories that the showrunners have said will be featured in the show to writings that Tolkien has written.**

To answer about specifically how the show adapts anything would need to wait until that part of the show is actually out.

The showrunners have said that Amazon's *The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power* is supposed to cover all of the major events of the mid-to-late second age.

> This is a title that we imagine could live on the spine of a book next to J.R.R. Tolkien’s other classics. **The Rings of Power unites all the major stories of Middle-earth’s Second Age: the forging of the rings, the rise of the Dark Lord Sauron, the epic tale of Númenor, and the Last Alliance of Elves and Men.** Until now, audiences have only seen on-screen the story of the One Ring –but before there was one, there were many… and we’re excited to share the epic story of them all.
> <sub>[Showrunners J.D. Payne & Patrick McKay, Variety.com](https://variety.com/2022/tv/news/lord-of-the-rings-rings-of-power-amazon-series-1235156784/)</sub>

Let's look at each of these four items one by one, and see which of Tolkien's writings they best correspond to:

1. **The forging of the rings**

   This is briefly covered in Appendix B from *The Lord of the Rings* (as well as a few places in the main text like "Shadows of the Past" and "The Council of Elrond").

   It is covered in more depth in the first half of "Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age" in *The Silmarillion*.
2. **The rise of the Dark Lord Sauron**

   This is harder to find a specific work for, and is more or less covered in the same texts that talk about the other three things in this list.
3. **The epic tale of Númenor**

   The Fall of Numenor is a story that Tolkien has written around ten times, under various titles. In particular:

   - The Akallabêth (*The Silmarillion*, *The Peoples of Middle-earth*)
   - The Fall of Númenor (*The Lost Road and Other Writings*, *Sauron Defeated*)
   - The Drowning of Anadûnê (*Sauron Defeated*)

   It also features prominently in the opening of Appendix A and B from *The Lord of the Rings*, and in the second half of The Notion Club Papers (*Sauron Defeated*).

   Tolkien has also written a few side stories set *in* Numenor, but which do not tell the story of the fall itself, such as "Aldarion and Erendis" (*Unfinished Tales*), and "The Númenórean chapters" (*The Lost Road*).
4. **The Last Alliance of Elves and Men**

   This is best covered in the Appendix A, Appendix B, and "The Council of Elrond" from *The Lord of the Rings*, as well as "Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age" in *The Silmarillion*.

**However it should be noted that Amazon does not necessarily have the rights to most of this.**

The only work that we know Amazon has the rights to is *The Lord of the Rings* and its appendices. There has been some speculation that they may have access to more on a case by case basis, but as of yet the only indication of such has been the maps they have been using.

Comment: [See also this other answer for a complete list of Tolkien's published Second Age writings.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/265877/55866)

Comment: The issue is that they don't have the rights to any of that,. Only to The Lord of the Rings and its appendices.

Comment: @OrangeDog - They've used other sources to make their maps, both the one in 2019 for marketing, and the one used in the actual show and trailers. So despite what they've been saying there clearly are instances where they are allowed to pull from other sources.

Comment: @OrangeDog For instance, the name Belegaer does not appear anywhere in LotR, but it's appeared in maps (it's mentioned three times in the 1977 Silmarillion, even, and twice in Unfinished Tales). Similarly with details about the geography of Númenor. And likewise, there are things shown on screen and not named, but for people who know the book texts, it's clear what they are meant to be: for example, Ost-in-edhil is not named, but it's an easy guess it's the city shown in Eregion.

Comment: So, in other words, they are as close to what Tolkien wrote as the Tolkien estate will let them get away with.

Comment: @nebogipfel - Not completely. Some changes are being made for pacing reasons, presumably for others as well.

Comment: @ibid Is it worth watching though?

Comment: @TheAsh - so far I've found it satisfactorily entertaining and watchable. Only two episodes in though and taste is subjective.

Comment: @ibid Did you watch the entire season?

Comment: @SDH - Yes, but I have nothing to add to my answer. It remains an answer about the five seasons overall, linking each of the major plot element to its source material. One could make a more detailed answer focusing specifically on season one, but due to the nature of the adaptation it's not going to be that simple to do and I'm not really interested.

Comment: @ibid Your answer was great but I was really wondering about whether you enjoyed it as a show. Did you like it?

Comment: @SDH - Overall I enjoyed it as a show. I think it would have been better had I waited to the end and binged it though, as some of the twists were way too obvious when having a week to reflect between episodes.

Answer (score 3):

Tolkien wrote comparatively little on the Second Age, so entire story is a bare-bones outline that it seems that someone could easily use to work within. But Amazon has taken a lot of *substantial* liberties with the stories. It make sense that a lot has to be *added*, because there's not much to go on, but quite a lot has been changed, with the "actual" occurences being treated more along the lines of call-backs or nods-and-winks.

**Firstly**, the biggest and most obvious change is that the entire story has been compressed *dramatically.* In the Appendices to the Lord of the Rings, the primary source material used *very loosely* in the show, here is the outline of events, up to the last thing that has occurred in the show:

c 500 SA. Sauron begins to stir in Middle-Earth.

c 1000 SA. Sauron makes Mordor his stronghold and begins building Barad-dur.

1200 SA. Sauron begins working with the smiths of Eregion.

c 1500 SA. The Elves and Sauron begin forging the Rings of Power - this must mean the 7 and the 9.

c 1590 SA. Celebrimbor completes the Three.

c 1600 SA. Sauron completes the One Ring, and Barad-dur. The War between the Elves and Sauron almost immediately begins.

1699 SA. Sauron overruns all of Eriador after destroying Eregion and killing Celebimbor.

1700 SA. Tar-Ministatir sends naval expedition to relieve Lindon. In the following centuries, the Numenoreans establish colonies and 'dominions' on the coasts. Sauron focuses on the East, but still rules much of Eriador.

2251 SA. The Nazgul first appear.

~3175-3255 SA. The 'repentance' of Tar-Palantir from the increasingly bad behavior of the Numenoreans; civil war in Numenor referenced in the show; Miriel and Ar-Pharazon.

In the show, we can clearly see *at least* 2200 years of events have been condensed into at most a few months. None of the Numenorean characters on the show would be born for more than a thousand years when Celebrimbor made the Three.

**Secondly**, another substantial change is the treatment of the Fading of the Elves. Clearly, this did make its way into the show...as an entirely separate idea, the concept that "corruption" in Middle Earth killing their tree will soon extinguish the Light of Valinor in them and force them to flee Middle-Earth. Strangely, Elves that never visited Valinor seem to be under the same affliction, and Gil-Galad is treated as the High King of all the Elves, and not only the Noldor - other Elves seem to hardly exist. This ties into the strange plotline where mithril is given all sorts of magical properties it does not have in the books and to have been formed as a result of a magical conflict between an Elf and a Balrog, which it was not. In short, the Fading was not an imminent disaster facing all living Elves - there was no reason *most* of them *had* to leave ME in the Second Age.

**Thirdly**, a lot of characters are busy doing things in the show that they should not have been doing, or that don't make a lot of sense. As the chief example, Galadriel missed out on the War of Wrath, because she and Celeborn
left Beleirand before the Fall of Nargothrond. In the Second Age, Galadriel and Celeborn were busy having their daughter, and were regarded as the Lord and Lady of Eriador, and they founded (!) Eregion. But by the time of the forging of the Rings, Galadriel and Celeborn were already dwelling in (what was later called) Lothlorien. She was certainly not wandering around the North looking for Sauron, because she already felt that whatever evil was in Middle-Earth came from the *east*.

There are *lots and lots* of other little odds and ends that have a substantial impact on the story. For example, the palantir **could not see the future.** This is a major and unnecessary change (why can't Miriel just dream it?), and a King of Numenor would be in absolutely no danger from the use of a palantir. Or consider that in the original timeline, the Three Rings were the culmination of the Elves' Ring-work, where in the series, they were the *first Rings made*, no prior "essays in the craft" of lesser Rings or Great Rings necessary. Similarly, by the timeline of the Lord of the Rings that the show supposedly uses as its main reference, the Istari do not arrive until later in the Third Age (later writings have two arrive in the Second Age, but still by ship), and certainly not Gandalf, and they arrive by ship and in control of their faculties and not on meteors. It is not clear to me why the cultists think Maiar should be confused: I presume this is drawn from Gandalf the White's condition, but his is a very special case and not at all true for Ainur in general.

There are also truly minor quibbles - people seem very upset about dwarven women, which are supposed to be indistinguishable from the men (to outsiders), and it seems hardly likely that anyone would describe Miriel as *fairer than silver or ivory or pearls.*

**In sum, the Rings of Power should be seen as only very *loosely* based on Tolkien. One could hardly expect it to be faithful to the *spirit* of Tolkien in this era, but even the narrative details are a loose guide at best.**

Comment: Just to mention the obvious point that the word "fair" is often used to mean "beautiful" by Tolkien. He even went out of his way to describe Idril as fair *and* pale, and that it is the latter that was the reason for her nickname "silver-foot". Or you may have been meaning the actress playing Míriel is unlovely, but that's clearly subjective :-) Did I ever previously imagine Míriel as a POC? No, but then I'm a white middle-aged guy with all the usual privileges. And I have a hard time visualising written characters anyway.